# Route to Default page is mixed with defined Route?

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, routes, defined

Here is my defined routes?

I got error for Link controller because its mixed with Default.

How can i make them work well.

Thanks,

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "slug",
    url: "{slug}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Accounts", action = "index" }, constraints: new { slug = ".+" });


routes.MapRoute(
              name: "Default",
              url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
              defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

   
        //link index route 
        routes.MapRoute(
    name: "links",
              url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "links", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: I defined three routes here but links route is not working .

Comment: why do you need `links` one? It has the same `url` pattern, just delete it and everything should work.

Comment: because its mixed with slug value   mysite .com/me   is mixed with mysite .com/links                     me is slug and links is controller

Comment: What you are trying to solve with such route mapping?

Comment: Dear Guru,   I want to put table value in my url  and load special page.   like i want to call myme as db value .....like :  mysite .com/myme.   i did but slug and links controller mixed i added links then links and home mixed .   i am looking for final solution.  thanks for your help   , as you see my all three routes above.

Answer (score 0):

this has been solved by changing default

URL to (   url: "Home/{action}/{id}",)

specified Home as controller